# Singleton functions in a project with ARC and non-ARC?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-management

I am working on a project which is non-ARC. The project has a singleton class which is use like a global functions class.

Everything works fine. Except for the following problems:

- Added a class with ARC
- When the singleton class is accessed from the ARC based class, it works for the first time
- Probably it is releasing the singleton class and further calls to the singleton class crashes the app with message "message sent to de-allocated instance"

I can imagine that the ARC enabled class is kind of releasing the singleton object.

How can i overcome this?

Edit: Singleton Class initializer GlobalFunctions.m

```
#import "GlobalFunctions.h"
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import "UIImage+Tint.h"
#import "Reachability.h"
#if !TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    #define Type @"Device"
#else
    #define Type @"Simulator"
#endif

@implementation GlobalFunctions

#pragma mark {Synthesize}
@synthesize firstLaunch=_firstLaunch;
@synthesize context = _context;

#pragma mark {Initializer}
static GlobalFunctions *sharedGlobalFunctions=nil;


- (UIColor *)UIColorFromRGB:(NSInteger)red:(NSInteger)green:(NSInteger) blue {
    CGFloat nRed=red/255.0; 
    CGFloat nBlue=green/255.0;
    CGFloat nGreen=blue/255.0;    
    return [[[UIColor alloc]initWithRed:nRed green:nBlue blue:nGreen alpha:1] autorelease];
}

#pragma mark {Class Intialization}
+(GlobalFunctions *)sharedGlobalFunctions{
    if(sharedGlobalFunctions==nil){
       // sharedGlobalFunctions=[[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
        sharedGlobalFunctions=[[GlobalFunctions alloc] init]; //Stack Overflow recommendation, does'nt work
        // Custom initialization
        /* 
         Variable Initialization and checks
        */
        sharedGlobalFunctions.firstLaunch=@"YES";   
        id appDelegate=(id)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];        
        sharedGlobalFunctions.context=[appDelegate managedObjectContext];
    }
    return sharedGlobalFunctions;
}

-(id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone{
    return self;
}
-(id)retain{
    return self;
}
-(NSUInteger) retainCount{
    return NSUIntegerMax;
}
-(void) dealloc{
    [super dealloc];
    [_context release];
}
@end
```

GlobalFunctions.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface GlobalFunctions : NSObject<UIApplicationDelegate>{
    NSString *firstLaunch;

}

+(GlobalFunctions *)sharedGlobalFunctions; //Shared Object 
#pragma mark {Function Declarations}
-(UIColor *)UIColorFromRGB:(NSInteger)red:(NSInteger)green:(NSInteger) blue; // Convert color to RGB

#pragma mark {Database Objects}
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSManagedObjectContext *context;


@end
```

Edit:

Tried using [[GlobalFunctions alloc] init] as Anshu suggested. But still the app crashes with message "sent to deallocated instance"

Comment: How'd you implement your singleton? As long as you have a strong reference to the object, there's no reason ARC should randomly release it. Sounds more like a problem with your singleton implementation.

Comment: Hi Anshu, i have added the initializer of my singleton class - am pretty sure it's not right? is it?

Comment: I don't think you want to use `allocWithZone:` here. The [ARC release notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html) say you can't use memory zones anymore anyway. Try just `[[GlobalFunctions alloc] init]`.

Comment: Thanks, but will that effect the non-ARC part of the project?

Comment: It shouldn't affect non-ARC parts of the project. Though I find the easiest way to avoid that question is to just use ARC for everything :P

Comment: I shall give it a shot and post back. Unfortunately, converting my whoe project to ARC is not a very convenient thing to do. But shall keep that in mind :)  - Edit: Does'nt work, posted as an edit

Comment: How is `sharedGlobalFunctions` declared? Something like `static GlobalFunctions* __strong sharedGlobalFunctions`?

Comment: Hey fabrice, edited my question to show the declaration as well

Comment: Well, I meant `sharedGlobalFunctions` the static variable you use in `+sharedGlobalFunctions` the method, and not `+sharedGlobalFunctions` the method.

Comment: I have posted my .m and .h files as it is - to access the methods i usually use [[GlobalFunctions sharedGlobalFunctions] UIColorFromRGB:0:0:0]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, remove the `copyWithZone:`, `retain` and `retainCount` methods;  they are useless in a singleton.

Secondly, that `dealloc` method is wrong;  `[super dealloc]` *must always be the last statement*.

The problem is your singleton itself;  you override `retain` to do nothing, but don't override `release`.   The ARC'd class is likely calling `retain` at the beginning of a scope and `release` at the end.   Since the singleton's `release` still actually decrements the retain count, the singleton is deallocated.

Remove the various methods as mentioned above and it should just work.

Note that your `GlobalFunctions` class shouldn't be declared as implementing `<UIApplicationDelegate>` as it is not the app's delegate.  Also, having two means of grabbing the same managed object context is odd (but not fatal).

Comment: That definitely worked, guess i got a lot to learn on OOPS. I just coul'dnt find any proper material that describes things that you have mentioned. Any books or material that you can suggest?

Comment: I stuck with the Apple (then NeXT) provided documentation from years ago.  I'm not sure what books to recommend these days.